# How do i prove this Continuity Theorem in metric spaces?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

let $(M_j,d_j) $ be a metric spaces

$f$ is continous in $M_1 \Leftrightarrow \forall $ closed $C\subset M_2, f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $M_1 $

C in my notes is an f, but that makes no sense, so ill put a C, if u think f makes sense please tell me why.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: How is continuity defined in your notes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof 1: Def: $f: (M_{1}, d_{1}) \rightarrow (M_{2}, d_{2})$ is continuous if and only if for all open set $O \in M_{2}$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $M_{1}$.

Let $C$ be closed in $M_{2}$. Then $f^{-1}(O) = f^{-1}(M_{2} \backslash C) = M_{1} \backslash f^{-1}(C)$ is open by the continuity of $f$ and it follows that $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed since it is a complement of an open set.

Proof 2: Def: A subset C of a metric space $M_{2}$ is closed iff for
every sequence $x_{k}$ that converges to some $x \in M_{2}$ we
necessarily have that $x \in C$.

Now suppose $C$ is closed. We wish to show that $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed. Let $x_{k} \in f^{-1}(C)$ be a sequence converging to some $x \in M_{1}$. Then by continuity [this is where we are using the fact that we are in a metric space], $f(x_{k})$ converges to $f(x)$. Since $f(x_{k}) \in C$, we have $f(x) \in C \implies x \in f^{-1}(C)$. We are done.